# Python PIL And People detection from ImageGrab.grab

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to adjusting the code of people detectiong and drawing boxes around them to this code:

```
while(True):
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40, 1680, 1050)))
    new_screen = process_img(screen)

    print('Loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
    last_time = time.time()
    cv2.imshow('window', new_screen)
    #cv2.imshow('NotAFortniteCheat', cv2.cvtColor(screen, 
    cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

This is working but trying to add people detection on it throws me too many errors and makes me think people detection can be only on images or premade videos and not live captures?

Tried:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector( cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector() )
while(True):
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab)
    found,w=hog.detectMultiScale(screen, winStride=(8,8), padding=(32,32), 
    scale=1.05)
    draw_detections(screen,found)
    new_screen = process_img(screen)
    cv2.imshow('feed',new_screen)
    ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
    if ch == 27:
        break
```

Comment: @abarnert Not duplicate since I'm asking on live detect. Those are all correlated to pictures, and nowhere is stated something about live imagegrab

Comment: Whether an image comes from a live imagegrab or a scan of a photo has some effect on the image, but not much—not nearly as much as, say, the contents of the image. Did you read the answer and the two links in that question? If it sounds like they shouldn't apply to your images, you'll need to show some example images, or describe why you think they should work with HOG instead of one of the other human detectors, or ideally both.

Comment: @abarnert yes and after linking threads to linking threads now I found a solution.
Another issue popped out, how do I link somebody? How do I know that person is person X and if I get another picture in which he is there it will say Person X, is it doable?